# Consequences for invalid BMS wire and its diagnosis

Tags: short-circuit, bms, bad-wiring

While re-assembling the 16S BMS, I didn't notice that the socket for one 8s pack was different from the socket for the other 8s pack until I connected the plug (image 4) to the battery tape, when small sparks appeared when the socket pins touched (battery side). I immediately pulled my hand away from the battery socket with the plug.

My questions:

1. What could be the consequences for an such event for this circuit swap none to B0? Did I fry something on PCB?

[image]

2. How to start and run diagnostics in this case (if I have no way to check via rs or can) if BMSis not working properly?

a) Visually I can't see anything on BMS PCB nor on battery tape with thermistors. In case of properly working BMS the relay fires twice after switching on. in this case once  and diodes are lit which should go off after coding BMS (the same result I did have while I did not connected one of 8S wiring to BMS)

b) On battery there is small glitch / bubble but it's not on right (down) related to B0 but to on the plug left (up).

[image]
[image]

Rest of it looks ok.

3. What the b0 is for?
4. Can I measure the voltage of each B? if so how? Which negative should I use to close circuit to measure it?  For the T there is +/- should I measure the resistance of the circuit to know the thermistor is ok? There are some values on the tape checkup.
5. Do I need to unscrew and lift up the tape to track the b0 pathway?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ) visual inspection brought/drawn my attention to mentioned **pack tape (with sensors and balancing circuits) bubble issue**

II ) some basic possible testing (mentioned bellow) shows this is **definitively an tape issue** as:

1. the issued storage **BMS PCB works** with other battery pack (i did swap the pack from second storage)
2. the **battery with broken tape** was tested with second BMS PCB (i swap the battery pack with probably broken tape to the second working storage) and the issue remains - BMS starts and after while shows RED lcd light issuing some startup problem

II) in next step i'm **planning to measure voltage/resistance for T1/T2 termistors** and **check if there is a circuit and voltage for other paths to terminals  with the plug from pack tape** - to narrow the place for **possible path or resistor burnout**